# Spring boot REST api ConstraintViolationException on password field

Tags: java, spring, rest, angular

I'm having a weird issue on my Spring backend, where I am sending a post request with a domain User object from my angular2 frontend that is being recieved by a REST API endpoint and translating it into the Spring User model object. The issue is that the password field from the JSON request seems to not be translating to the password field on the backend. All the other fields (username, name, email, etc.) are coming through fine, but the password is null.

Request payload as seen from network tab in chrome

> email : "asdf@asdf.com" firstName : "asdfasdjk" lastName : "asdfs"
> login : "adfsjk" password : "fasdfasdfasdsd"

Response seen from network tab

> error: "Internal Server Error" exception: "javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException" message: "Validation failed for classes [domain.User] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
>
> List of constraint violations:[    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='may not be null', propertyPath=password, rootBeanClass=class domain.User, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}'}]"
> path:"/api/users" status: 500

**Spring Rest method:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users",
        method = RequestMethod.POST,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@Timed
public ResponseEntity<User> createUser(@RequestBody User user) throws URISyntaxException {
    User result = userRepository.save(user);
    return ResponseEntity.created(new URI("/api/users/" + result.getId()))
            .headers(HeaderUtil.createEntityCreationAlert("user", result.getId().toString()))
            .body(result);
}
```

**Spring domain object**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class User extends AbstractAuditingEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 100)
    @Column(length = 100, unique = true)
    private String login;

    @JsonIgnore
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 5, max = 60)
    @Column(length = 60)
    private String password;

    @Size(max = 50)
    @Column(name = "first_name", length = 50)
    private String firstName;

    @Size(max = 50)
    @Column(name = "last_name", length = 50)
    private String lastName;

    @Email
    @Size(max = 100)
    @Column(length = 100, unique = true)
    private String email;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_tag",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "users_id", referencedColumnName =     "ID"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tags_id", referencedColumnName = "ID"))
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    private List<Tag> tags = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

**Angular2 domain object**

```
export class User {

   id: number;
   login: string;
   password: string;
   firstName: string;
   lastName: string;
   email: string;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with using `@JsonIgnore` on the password field, this makes the filed ignorable when reading from or writing to JSON message, one solution is to use [`@JsonProperty`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html) with `access = Access.WRITE_ONLY` as follows

```
public class User extends AbstractAuditingEntity implements Serializable {

  // Other fileds

  @NotNull
  @JsonProperty(access = Access.WRITE_ONLY)
  @Size(min = 5, max = 60)
  @Column(length = 60)
  private String password;

}
```

Another solution is to implement a getter and setter for the password field, and annotate the getter with [`@JsonIgnore`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnore.html) and the setter with [`@JsonProperty`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html), as follows

```
public class User extends AbstractAuditingEntity implements Serializable {

  // Other fileds

  @NotNull
  @Size(min = 5, max = 60)
  @Column(length = 60)
  private String password;

  @JsonIgnore
  public String getPassword() {
    return password;
  }

  @JsonProperty
  public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
  }

}
```